# Visual Studio Team Services "stuck" in project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I have set up a number of projects on Git VSTS, and all was fine.

I then tried to add another solution to source control today, but the status bar along the bottom said it was already under one of the previous source control projects I set up - which is in a sibling folder.

The File->Source Control menu item was missing so I couldn't look at bindings or anything.

In the end, I moved all the projects and solution files to a differently named folder, and the normal status bar "Add to source control" item came back.

My question is, why does moving the files work? There were no hidden .git or .vs folders - this solution had never been added to source control before.

What is it doing? Is there a way to fix this if it happens again without renaming the solution folder?

**Additional info**: I tried disconnecting from TFS and opening the project I wanted to add, but that had no effect - so I presume that's because it thinks it's using the local git repository?

If I look at Team Explorer once disconnected from TFS, then all remote repositories are disconnected as I'd expect, but the local Git one the common code repository is bold still as the current repository - and there seems to be no way of disconnecting from local repositories?

Comment: Could you share  the entire error log? Have you restarted VS/Team Explorer? Can the original folder be able to add to source control? Maybe it's VS/Team Explorer cache issue.

Comment: Where would I find the error log?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to clean the cache folder to see whether it helps you. The folder path is: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache`.

Comment: Nope, that didn't do it. The solution contains common projects that are under source control on another project, and it seems to be picking that up. However the solution and most of the app projects are not under source control - but I can't add them because there doesn't seem to be a way of convincing VS to not think it's under source control.

Comment: Please see additional info

Comment: I have got it to work by going to options and changing the source control plugin to "none", which brought back the "Add Solution to Source Control" option. I'd still like to know WHY this all occurred though!